# Send both POST and GET in HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a form that sends submitted data to both email and a .txt file when pressing Submit.

After some research here on Stack Overflow I'm now a bit stuck.

I made a new action in the  tag and if the "send-email.php" file name is correct in "new_action.php" only the email function works.
If I have the "send-email.php" incorrect or delete it, the "get-data.php" (using $_GET) works fine.
So yeah, I want both to work.

I guess there's something wrong with the Javascript?

Here's the whole chain:

HTML

```
<form name="form-name" method="Post" action="new_action.php" id="form-one" onsubmit="process()">
```

NEW_ACTION.PHP

```
<?php
  include('send-email.php');
  include('get-data.php');
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function process() {
  var form = document.getElementById('form-one');
  var elements = form.elements;
  var values = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    values.push(encodeURIComponent(elements[i].name) + '=' + 
encodeURIComponent(elements[i].value));

  form.action += '?' + values.join('&');
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse "Data in the query string" and "Data in the request body" with "GET" and "POST" (even if PHP does).

Comment: Why are you appending the same fields to the action as in the post body?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (you said something is going wrong in one of your includes, but you haven't shown us that code — don't forget to ensure your MCVE is minimal!) and a *clear problem statement* (which "only the email function works" is not).

Comment: To start - you are adding "?" for EVERY action, you only want one (else it'll break). Second - GET and POST are the same thing (in the simplest terms), GET will show in the request URI, and post will keep it hidden, meaning POST is more secure and wanna use that

Comment: @SamSwift웃 It really has nothing to do with being secure..... yeah it is visible in the url, but that is not really the reasoning.

Comment: Okay, sorry for not providing the whole thing - I thought this was enough. I changed to $_POST in "get-data.php" now, so now my only question is: How do I get both functions (email and post to .txt) to work at the same time? At the moment, with the provided code, only one of them works at a time.